# How can i handle Intent after pressing previous activity back button?

Tags: android

Application have three activity. first_Activity.java, second_Activity.java and Third_Activity.java

In my first_activity.java set intent to the second_activity and in the Second_Activity.java get intent from first_activity .

In Second_Activity i set the intent go to the third_activity.
I set the actionbar.sethomeupasenable(true) in second and third_activity.

Here is my First_activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_first);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("name", "Milan");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here, is my second_activity.java

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    String name="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Intent i=getIntent();
        name=i.getStringExtra("name");

        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_second);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main22Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name1",name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is my third activity.java

```
public class Main22Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main22);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Intent i=getIntent();
        String name1=i.getStringExtra("name1");

        Log.e("Name",""+name1);
    }
}
```

Here is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.milan.intentflowdemo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity"></meta-data>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Main22Activity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".Main2Activity"></meta-data>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Sorry not getting an error but the problem is after pressing back button of action bar of third activity second activity is automatically refresh.

Instead of when i pressing the device back button second activity not refresh.
I wan this on action bar back button.

Please help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: Please add more detail. Show some code and show what exception you are getting.

Comment: Post your code of activity transition to understand the flow and intent passing

Comment: Tip: don't name all your activities MainActivityXYZ

Comment: What do you exactly want to happen here? when up is enabled the parent activity will be created and not resumed. please provide more details on what you want to happen

Comment: Actually i want like if i press back button of third activity my second activity will not be refresh.As same as if i press back button of second activity my first activity will not be refresh.